# How can I see all the actions attached to an "add_action" hook?

Tags: plugins, php, hooks, actions, debug

I'm working with the admin bar and trying to debug some of the menus and their priorities.

I know several callbacks get bound to actions, such as this one:

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_wp_menu', 10 );
```

How can I see what is lined up to be called when a hook like `admin_bar_menu` is called?

Comment: Hook onto the shutdown action and print the `$wp_filters` global or similar? .. not got a working WP install right now to say in absolution... (but i know there's a global with filters and/or actions).. just a pointer.. ;)

Comment: awesome - just it needs to be singular `$wp_filter`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can see the detailed list of the hook using this snippet:

```
$hook_name = 'admin_bar_menu';
global $wp_filter;
var_dump( $wp_filter[$hook_name] );
```

Comment: almost right. needs to be `$wp_filter` singular. thanks.

Comment: Right, answer updated.

Comment: Is there an easy place that this can be placed so that it can be tested? I realize that this is pretty old, but anyone?

Comment: You can put it in header or footer, using `wp_head`, `wp_footer` or `shutdown` hook. Note: if you don't want users to see this debug information, you should check user permission by `if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {...}`

Comment: I use some functions to format it more nicely. Useful if you use it often for debugging and want to see the info quicker. Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/JDGrimes/9020183).

Comment: Good answer! Thanks a lot. Just added <pre> tags to make it format nicely and was able to find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A list of callback functions:

```
// list call back functions
    $hook_name = 'admin_bar_menu';
    global $wp_filter;
    echo '<h2>  Hook name: '.  $hook_name . '</h2> ';
    if( isset( $wp_filter[$hook_name]->callbacks )){
        if (is_array($wp_filter[$hook_name]->callbacks )){
        echo '<h2>callback functions > accepted_args </h2>';
            foreach(  $wp_filter[$hook_name]->callbacks as $item){
                if ( is_array( $item)){
                    foreach ( $item as $subitem){
                        echo '<P>'.  $subitem['function'].' '.$subitem['accepted_args'] . '</P>';
                    }
                    
                }
            }
    }}
```