# Post Content, Special Characters and Filters

Tags: filters, hooks, the-content, encoding, escaping

I added a hook to `the_content`.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'edit_the_content');
function edit_the_content($content){
    return $content;
}
```

Pretty simple right?

However, when it output `$content` from within my `edit_the_content()` callback it seems like WordPress converts some, but not all characters into special characters.

**Example:**

it's = `it&#8217;s`

but then an anchor tag, remains untouched and not converted.

Is there some sort of filter which runs on `the_content` which only converts some characters to special characters, but not all?

Comment: I would like to know what causes this to happen, but as a short-term solution, I am able to use `html_entity_decode($content)` to properly check the `$content` value.

Comment: Hm, not sure... how is the value stored in the database, is it "it's" or "it&#8217;s"?

Comment: @simonthesorcerer The value in the database is stored like `it's`

Comment: @simonthesorcerer In-case you're curious... I found the culprit, along with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a snippet of code like [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/35085/9579):

```
$hook_name = 'the_content';
global $wp_filter;
var_dump($wp_filter[$hook_name]);
```

I was able to find a list of all hooked callback functions to the WordPress filter: `the_content`.

I then located a few possible culprits, then searched for their function existence.

After narrowing down my list, I came to the conclusion on the hooked callback function causing the problem.

In the file `./wp-includes/default-filters.php` on **line 135** as of *WordPress 3.6* there is a hooked function `add_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');`

In the file `./wp-includes/formatting.php` on **line 29** as of *WordPress 3.6* there is the function definition of [`wptexturize()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wptexturize).

```
/**
 * Replaces common plain text characters into formatted entities
 *
 * As an example,
 * <code>
 * 'cause today's effort makes it worth tomorrow's "holiday"...
 * </code>
 * Becomes:
 * <code>
 * &#8217;cause today&#8217;s effort makes it worth tomorrow&#8217;s &#8220;holiday&#8221;&#8230;
 * </code>
 * Code within certain html blocks are skipped.
 *
 * @since 0.71
 * @uses $wp_cockneyreplace Array of formatted entities for certain common phrases
 *
 * @param string $text The text to be formatted
 * @return string The string replaced with html entities
 */
```

**How to prevent WordPress from formatting `the_content` characters into HTML entities?**

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');
```

Lesson learned. Using that snippet of code at the beginning of this answer will help you to... at a minimum, find all the attached callback functions to a particular WordPress hook. Which is a great start, the rest may take a bit of searching and reading what each callback function does.